# How to get index of element from edit text

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, indexing

How can I code the following:

For example, I have one `EditText` in which I insert a word (or words) like "abcdawa". I have another `EditText` in which I enter the search element. Let's say I want to search "a".

When I click a `Button` the indexes of the word in the first `EditText` which equals the search element should be shown in a `TextView`. Expected output: 1, 5, 7

Comment: itterate through the user input ("abcdawa") then compare each letter with a. Keep an Array of integers which stores the position (+1). Example: the first a is on index 0, you store the number 1 in your array

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you have 2 edittext with id edText_1 & edText_2, and a button
Now in on click of your button call following,

```
setOnClickListener{
    String query = edText_2.getText().toString();
    char[] dataArray = edText_1.getText().toString().toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        if (query.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(dataArray[i]))) {
            textView.append(" " + i);
        }
    }
}
```